# Adding a dynamic unsubscribe button to a static block

Tags: magento, static-block, unsubscribe

First of all this concerns magento.
I want to have a newsletter with a standard header and footer. This header and footer are being built through static blocks.
How can i add a dynamic unsubscribe option in the static footer block? (an unsubscribe per customer)
And should this not be possible, how can I do it through other means?

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Patrick , are you want an form to unsubscribe  newsletter or just url

Answer (score 0):

First create a static block and call phtml from static block 
The  code  of .phtml file

call in a phtml file in  static block

```
   {{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/unsci.phtml" 
name="newsletterall" }}
```

**Create a phtml in unsci.phtml under app/design/frontend/yourpackage/youtemplate/newsletter**

Call a static block like the code is below-

If you want only to unsubscribe then you should add below code in phtml file

```
<?php        $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')
                    ->loadByEmail("dev.amit.bera@gmail.com")
 if( $subscriber->getId()){ 
            $unscibeurl=Mage::helper('newsletter')->getUnsubscribeUrl($subscriber); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo echo $unscibeurl; ?>">Un subcribe</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Call static block in anywhere using below code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($indenfirename)->toHtml();  ?>
```